# Laravel Cashier with Stripe - test cards always fail with "incomplete" requiring additional action

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am trying to test my Cashier implementation. I am using test card 4242 4242 4242 4242. I am using Stripe test mode (test data and test api key). The card always fails with the message "additional action is required" and the subscriptions table record is marked "incomplete". I believe this card should require no further auth and always succeed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide the code of where you are creating these subscriptions?

Comment: It's a little complicated - I would do so but I think it might be irrelevant because everything works perfectly in NON TEST MODE. As I am adding a new feature I need to test it but I cannot get past this point when I am in test mode using a test card. As the code works 100% as expected in live mode with a real card I don't think showing the code would help. But do please correct me if you think I am wrong.